# Magento2 : Call phtml file to other phtml file

Tags: magento2, layout, template

I want to add new phtml file to existed phtml file. It is working fine, but I want to know reference block and class names.

My code in layout file

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>       
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Test::test.phtml"/>
</body>
```

In layout file, Here I need to add reference block/container or no need?

Existed code phtml file is

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Test::test.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layout Method**

If you want to added another phtml file using the layout, then you need to give name to your block like this one :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>       
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mytestblock" as="mytestblock" template="Magento_Test::test.phtml"/>
</body>
```

then you can use like `refrenceBlock="mytestblock"` to call another phtml using layout.

**Direct Method**

You want to call phtml into another phtml then you can use this code.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Test::newtest.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: so existed block name i need to add in layout file like           <referenceBlock name="existed block name"> 
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Test::test.phtml"/>         </referenceBlock>

Comment: yes, you can use like that.

Comment: If answer help, please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: sure, then i will give class name also existed name like this  <block class="Magento\Test\Block\Testname" intstead of  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"